# How to handle only new data when you receive XML or CSV file which contains all data (old & new) daily

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming, spark-structured-streaming

I receive an XML or CSV file which contains all data (old & new) each day. For example, if Yesterday.xml contains 3 records, Today.xml contains 4 records (3 old and one new).

I am only concerned with the last one (new row) as I only want to process new data, old data is processed day by day.

What is the best approach to implement this using Spark and Kafka?
Data example:

```
OpportunityNo, OpprotunityTitle,Field
--- yesterday data----
Row1:1,OppTit1,IT
Row2:2,OppTit2,HEALTH
Row3:3,OppTit3,Finance
-------today data---------
Row4:4,OppTit4,Engineering
```

Additional Notes:

1. The file is a very large one. i.e. processing the file is costly especially it could have in today.xml and update for 2nd row which is related to yesterday's data, but since an update occur to it, it should be taken as a today update.
2. I need to write the new (and updated) data to a database (as a sink).
3. the aim from all this is to recommend new records to persons who has same major. i.e if my major is IT then, on login, I will get recommended OppTit1, once I open this OppTitle1, I will be moved to a historical recommendation table, and like this, any new data will be inserted to a recommendation table once opened will move to historical one, where use can get back and see it.

If there is no way other than processing the XML, I would like to know your suggestions about how to design it.

My code is below, but it gets all data on each new file goes to the directory, I want only to get the new data not all data.

```
import org.apache.log4j._
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.{ StructType, StructField, IntegerType, DoubleType, StringType, TimestampType, DateType }
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import org.apache.spark.sql.streaming.OutputMode
import org.apache.spark.sql.streaming.Trigger

object Demo {
    def main(args: Array[String]) {
            Logger.getLogger("org").setLevel(Level.ERROR)

            val conf = new SparkConf()
            conf.set("spark.app.name", "GrantAnalytics")
            conf.set("spark.master", "local")
            val sc = new SparkContext(conf)

            val spark = SparkSession.builder().appName("GrantAnalytics").master("local[*]").getOrCreate()

            spark.conf.set("spark.sql.shuffle.partitions", 5)
            val schema = new StructType(Array(
              new StructField("OpportunityID", IntegerType, true),
              new StructField("OpportunityTitle", StringType, true),
              new StructField("OpportunityNumber", StringType, true),
              new StructField("CFDANumbers", DoubleType, true),
              new StructField("CategoryOfFundingActivity", StringType, true)))

            val streamingDF = spark.readStream.schema(schema).option("maxFilesPerTrigger", 1).option("header", "true").format("csv").load("C:/datasets/output/*.csv")

            val query = streamingDF.select(concat(col("OpportunityID"), lit("~"), col("OpportunityTitle"), lit("~"), col("OpportunityNumber"), lit("~"), col("CFDANumbers"), lit("~"), col("CategoryOfFundingActivity")).alias("value")).writeStream.format("kafka").outputMode(OutputMode.Update()).option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092").option("topic", "grants").option("checkpointLocation", "C:/deleteme/kafka/").start()
            query.awaitTermination()
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**If you want to work with Kafka it is best to think in individual and independent events when designing your application.**

This means, you should split the XML into Rows and filter it by a data/timestamp to send each message to Kafka. In Kafka every message contains exactly one Row from your example data. In the end, after the second day, Kafka should contain the following four messages:

```
1,OppTit1,IT
2,OppTit2,HEALTH
3,OppTit3,Finance
4,OppTit4,Engineering
```

Also, make sure to apply a useful key for the Kafka message.

As soon as the data is available in Kafka as single events, you can use Spark to consume and process only new messages that refer to the current day as previously consumed messages will not be consumed again.

Comment: The xml is given with rows that do not contain date and time, and if I added that column, it will be added to all rows, otherwise, I will process this xml against the previous xml (today vs yesterday), which is costly. Is there a way that Kafka or spark can determine that this record is already ingested (i.e. kafka or spark can determine that this record is already read and processed then it will skip it).